# Is there an MSDN Developer Library Equivalent for Xcode + Mac OS X?

Tags: c++, xcode

I'm begginer with studying C++ using Xcode. I'm familiar with MSDN for Windows. Is there an equivalent developer resource library for Xcode on Mac OS X ?

Comment: Are you asking about where to find *documentation* for XCode?

Comment: From the "Help" menu choose "API reference" or "Documentation", or type into the quick search box.

Comment: Dammit, Das, how can I up-vote your answer when its in a comment?. This *is* the answer to his question. Get thee to the editor so I can burn another up vote. purty-plz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple has a developer library at https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/

This covers all Apple's *platform specific* technologies and APIs.

This information can also be downloaded and accessed within Xcode, if you just look around in the Xcode settings.

However, since you say you're learning C++ and you may be used to the C++ standard library documentation on MSDN you should know that Apple's developer library does not include documentation on the standard C++ library. Nor is there any reason for it to include this stuff. This would only be duplicating widely available information.

If you're looking for a good reference on the standard C++ library check out http://en.cppreference.com/